# No tests found when testCoverageEnabled

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I'm getting this error whenever I try to create a coverage report:

```
Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'

com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > No tests found.[Pixel 2 - 8.1.0] FAILED 
No tests found. This usually means that your test classes are not in the form that your test runner expects (e.g. don't inherit from TestCase or lack @Test annotations).
```

I modified a sample repo to reproduce the issue: 
https://github.com/suarezjulian/unified-code-coverage-android

just download and execute:

```
./gradlew jacocoTestReport
```

Answer (score 4):

You're running Test Orchestrator version 1.0.2, try lowering the version to 1.0.1.  I've had troubles with this too, maybe 1.0.2 doesn't play nicely with Jacoco.

Comment: Is there a bug filed with Google for this?

Comment: This solution worked for me, I had added `execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'` in gradle file but missed to add dependency that is `androidTestUtil 'androidx.test:orchestrator:1.3.0'`. Thanks